# Unity Android app will no longer log into Google Play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I have seen several threads around this issue but I am still struggling. 
My app is failing to sign in on Android with:

```
Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US
```

I had this all working about 4 months ago but my hard drive failed and I am trying to get things working again on a newer version of Unity. I am only having this problem with *NEW* builds. My old apk still works fine so everything must be fine in the Google Play Developer Console. Something is not setup right in Unity.

I have tried with and without setting the "OAuth2 Client ID" from the Developer Console in the Android settings.

I have tried setting the keystore to .android/debug.keystore using the androiddebugkey with "android" as the password for both.

What else could it be?

Comment: 403 means it´s a forbidden access. Are you sure you have used the correct SHA1 fingerprint?

Comment: You need to use the same keystore file as the previous build, otherwise you are in trouble for updating your app.

Comment: JeanLuc is correct, be sure it´s the same keystore. If you lost it, it´s no way to update your app (I guess)....

Comment: @JeanLuc I have not published the app yet and I am using the debug keystore. I might have used a different keystore in the old build but should that matter if I am trying to make a debug build now?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs If I am using the .android/debug.keystore do I need to set the SHA1 fingerprint somewhere or does Unity extract that from the keystore?

Comment: Yes it does matter, because all builds authenticate them self with the combination of keystore file and package name. If you want to add another authentication credentials go to the [Google API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient), select your project and create new credentials with the new keystore file and your package name.

Comment: BUT since you lost your old keystore file, delete your not yet published app, because you cann't update it anymore and create a new app with a new keystore file (not android debug), link that app to your Game. Then make sure you backup your keystore file somewhere safe from am hard drive failure.

Comment: @JeanLuc Thank you, that was the problem. I found my old file. I had backed it up, just didn't realize where. After using that, everything works again!

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

So to sum up my comments up in an answer, that might be useful to somebody else.

**1.) An app authenticates itself towards the Google Play Services with the combination of Keystore and Package name.**

You can't sign in without or with another keystore. So you should always backup the keystore file together with your project in a version control system, that is safe from a single hard drive failure.

---

**2.) If you lose keystore file, you can not update your app anymore.**

But you could create a new app and link it to the same Google Play Game.